# Pass back guess to other activity?

Tags: android

In one activity I have a guessing game where the user enters a guess into an edit text field. What I want to do is then take this guess and pass it to the other activity where it will be displayed as a toast. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you hitting errors in your code or are you simply unsure of passing information between activities? The question requires more information from you.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to use Intent's extras:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, class);
mIntent.putExtra(name, value);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

The second thing would be using shared preferences.
In the activity where the user inputs the value:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(name, value);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
prefs.putBoolean(name, value);
editor.commit();
```

And then to retrieve the value in the other activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(name, value);
boolean value = prefs.getBoolean(name, defaultValue);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for